# Where are the transformations saved in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

This maybe a basic question but I would like to know where are the transformations saved in Pentaho Data Integration. Currently, I am connecting to a repository and all my jobs and transformations are saved there.I would like to be able to say email a particular transformation to another person. I checked on the server if there are any .ktr files but could not find any. How can I save a transformation to my local desktop.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open from repository, then export to XML (under File menu).  Name the exported file the same as the transformation name in the repository.  The .ktr files are just XML.

To clarify:  the .ktr files actually *are* XML.  If you export the file as XML, but name it .ktr, you will be able to open and edit it with PDI/Spoon, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can I get the .ktr files as it is instead of exporting as XML?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file based repository: when choosing which repository to connect to, press the edit button (a small pencil) and that will show you the "base directory". That's where your jobs/transformations reside. Be careful not to mess with those files.

If you have a database based repository, then for things like sending a couple of tranformations via email, then you should follow @FremenFreedom advice.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I click on the edit button, I see a URL which is the Data Integration server. I would like to get the .ktr files essentially.

Comment: Then you have a Database Repo. So I guess the only way to get the ktr files is to follow @FremenFreedom advice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the open source tool called krex. It is written by Roland and very useful as it will export part or all of a database repo to Ktr and kjb files.

Best of all its a pdi job itself!